# error when trying to get a python irc bot to send a message to the channel

Tags: python, irc, bots

I have a super simple IRC bot that basically connects to a channel, when someone says "hello robot" it is supposed to say "Hello" in the channel and then exit. However, the bot doesn't say hello although I am able to get it to exit.

The code for it to send "Hello" to the channel is as follows:

```
s.send('PRIVMSG #test :%s\r\n' %s (MESSAGE))
```

The error I receive is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "defaultbot.py", line 40, in <module>
s.send('PRIVMSG #test :%s\r\n' %s (MESSAGE))
TypeError: '_socketobject' object is not callable
```

The script I am using is fairly short and I hope straight forward:

http://pastebin.com/iXwP3YJF

Comment: It seems that you pastebin link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

well i think that is because you are using s for the socket and %s for the string.

try to do this:

```
s.send('PRIVMSG #test :'+MESSAGE+'\r\n')
```

(also im creating an module for IRC bots in python, its not done yet but its functional (not sure if allowed to tell this here, if i'm not then delete this :)) https://github.com/FaceHunter/IRCbot )